# Magento 2 : Call a function at the time of module installation

Tags: magento2, custom, setup-script, install-script

I want to call a function to send some store information through api call at the time of my custom module installation. Is there any event observer for this? How can we do it? Thanks.

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMIN);
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
    $email = $this->authSession->getUser()->getEmail();

    $data = [
        'scope' => 'default',
        'scope_id' => 0,
        'path' => "[module]/general/email",
        'value' => $email,
    ];
    $setup->getConnection()
        ->insertOnDuplicate($setup->getTable('core_config_data'), $data, ['value']);}}
```